# Carriage return in values of arrays in Javascript not allowed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, carriage-return

I had this question about arrays in JavaScript.
I couldn't really find an answer. maybe i din look harder, i did look hard enough. or maybe i missed it in the book i am using as my reference.

I had an array and tried to push in quotes.

```
    var quotes =[];
    quotes.push("It has become appallingly obvious that our technology has exceeded 
    our humanity - Albert Einstein") /*i placed it on the second line to make 
                                       it more readable*/
```

This gave me an error. it did not state what error it was. I was going crazy thinking what could it be? i mean, what could i be missing in these 2 lines of code.

Then i placed it all on the same line and guess what, yes no more error. =_=

Can someone enlighten me on why? Or am i missing out on the obvious here.

Any response appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: thanks man. that site is awesome as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var quotes =[];
quotes.push("It has become appallingly obvious that our technology has exceeded \
    our humanity - Albert Einstein");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have newlines in a string. End the string first and concatenate it with a new one, like this;

```
quotes.push("It has become appallingly obvious that our technology has exceeded "
    + "our humanity - Albert Einstein");
```

If you actually want the newline to be part of the string use `"\n"` instead.

Comment: Saying "You can't have newlines in a string" is simply incorrect, either way you want to interpret it.

Comment: No it isn't. You can add the modifier "without escaping it" if you like, but he is putting a literal newline in the middle of a string - between `"`s if you like, and that's not valid. If you read it in context rather than being nitpicky, it won't be an issue.

Comment: i guess, if we look at it from the point of view of carriage returns... Thor84no is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
quotes.push("It has become appallingly obvious that our technology has exceeded " +
    "our humanity - Albert Einstein");
```

that would work; I also added a semicolon at the end of your line.

Answer (score 1):

```
var quotes =[];
quotes.push("It has become appallingly obvious that our technology has exceeded \
our humanity - Albert Einstein");
```

Notice the `\` at the end of line 2.
That's how you write multi-line strings in many languages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes on a single line will work because as you rightly pointed out, a carriage return does not work. That is, in Javascript a carriage return is considered end of a programming statement.